# Range based for-loop on array passed to non-main function

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, for-loop

When I try to compile the following code in gcc 4.8.2, I get the following error:

> ```
> test.cc: In function ‘void foo(int*)’:
> test.cc:15:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(int*&)’
>    for (int i : bar) {
>                 ^
> ```

Along with a bunch of others from deeper in the template library.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void foo(int*);

int main() {
  int bar[3] = {1,2,3};
  for (int i : bar) {
    cout << i << endl;
  }
  foo(bar);
}

void foo(int* bar) {
  for (int i : bar) {
    cout << i << endl;
  }
}
```

If I redefine `foo` to use an indexed for loop, then the code compiles and behaves as expected. Also, if I move the range-based output loop into `main`, I get the expected behaviour as well.

How do I pass the array `bar` to `foo` in such a way that it is capable of executing a range-based for-loop on it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With the [array decaying](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/1938163) into a pointer you're losing one important piece of information: its size.

With an array reference your range based loop works:

```
void foo(int (&bar)[3]);

int main() {
  int bar[3] = {1,2,3};
  for (int i : bar) {
    cout << i << endl;
  }
  foo(bar);
}

void foo(int (&bar)[3]) {
  for (int i : bar) {
    cout << i << endl;
  }
}
```

or, in a generic fashion (i.e. without specifying the array size in the function signature),

```
template <std::size_t array_size>
void foo(int (&bar)[array_size]) {
  for (int i : bar) {
    cout << i << endl;
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Try it out](http://ideone.com/hqC1cK)</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

For a fixed size array you can

- Pass a raw array by reference.
- Pass a `std::array` by reference.
- Pass a `std::vector` by reference.

The natural choice (for a fixed size array) is `std::array`, i.e.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

void foo(array<int, 3> const& bar) {
  for (int i : bar) {
    cout << i << endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  array<int,3> const bar = {1,2,3};
  for (int i : bar) {
    cout << i << endl;
  }
  foo(bar);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using C++20's `std::span`, you can have a reference to an array or runtime size.

Here's your code with `std::span` instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <span>

void foo(std::span<int>);

int main() {
  int bar[3] = {1,2,3};
  for (int i : bar) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }
  foo(bar);
}

void foo(std::span<int> bar) {
  for (int i : bar) { // now works
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }
}
```