# how can a for range loop infer a plain array size

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, for-loop, range

Consider this snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int s[6] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  for ( auto && i: s ) {
    std::cout << " " << i << std::endl;
  }
}
```

This compiles and runs happily both under g++ and clang++.
It is taken for granted in many posts([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297000/passing-array-to-a-function-and-using-it-in-for-range-loop]) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26182907/range-based-for-loop-on-array-passed-to-non-main-function), for example), but it is unclear to me how the compiler can correctly infer the size of the array in the `for range` for a type without iterator.
Can anyone answer or add a link to the reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the working draft [[6.5.4/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ranged#1)]:

> The range-based for statement
>
> ```
> for ( for-range-declaration : for-range-initializer ) statement
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> {
>   auto &&__range = for-range-initializer ;
>   auto __begin = begin-expr ;
>   auto __end = end-expr ;
>   for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin ) {
>       for-range-declaration = *__begin;
>       statement
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> where
>
> [...]
>
> begin-expr and end-expr are determined as follows:
>
> - if the for-range-initializer is an expression of array type R, begin-expr and end-expr are __range and __range + __bound, respectively, where __bound is the array bound. If R is an array of unknown size or an array of incomplete type, the program is ill-formed;
>
> [...]

So it works mostly as @VladFromMoscow has already mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

When the compiler compiles this statement

```
  for ( auto && i: s ) {
    std::cout << " " << i << std::endl;
```

it knows the type of the variable `s` that is `int[6]`.

So for arrays the compiler uses expressions like `s` and `s + 6` to define the range.